# ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast

Tags: android, exception

I am getting this ClassCaseException -

```
/ActivityManager(213): Bad activity token: android.os.BinderProxy@420b43f0
W/ActivityManager(213): java.lang.ClassCastException: android.os.BinderProxy cannot be cast to 
com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord$TokenW/ActivityManager(213): at 
com.android.server.am.ActivityRecord.forToken(ActivityRecord.java:295)
W/ActivityManager(213): at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.configureSoftkeysActivity(ActivityManagerService.java:15095)
W/ActivityManager(213): at android.app.ActivityManagerNative.onTransact(ActivityManagerNative.java:1572)W/ActivityManager(213):     at com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService.onTransact(ActivityManagerService.java:1646)
W/ActivityManager(213): at android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:338)
W/ActivityManager(213): at dalvik.system.NativeStart.run(Native Method)
```

Do any one has any idea why I am getting this exception. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Add some code where this exception is occuring

Comment: I think this issue has something to do with "https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/4502ce2d498e6173f69b5af88cb2b81b76de990f%5E%21/#F0"

Answer (score 18):

I know it's old, but thought I'd answer as I've just solved this myself. This (for me) is due to having `android:process` in my `Service` declaration of the application manifest. Simply removing that solved my issue immediately.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: I'm having this happen to me when the service is running on the same process, and have no idea how that's even possible. If anyone from the future sees this - please reply :) I've either fixed this or found a workaround.

Comment: I have the exact same issue. @Not_a_Golfer did you manage to understand and/or solve it ?

Comment: @NeTeInStEiN first of all, I've found the reason - it is because for some reason two processes of the same application are alive at once, mostly during an update. Is your service running as a sticky service? IIRC making the service non-sticky helped a bit.

Comment: How is that possible? It shouldn't be possible to have 2 processes of the same app..

Comment: It appears to be a bug in certain android versions, and looks like there's a correlation to low system resources

Answer (score 2):

If service to bind is in different process with the caller, you should use AIDL interface.